# Unity Pixel per unit

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, pixel

i hope you can help me ... I chose a sprite background of size 2048x1365. My camera size is 6. The aspect ratio is 4:3. This is the math i did to claculate the PPU for that sprite:

I multiply my camera size by two to get my camera height and got 12.

Then I divided the height of the sprite by the height of the camera to get PPU and got 113.75 PPU.

Then I set the sprite PPU to 113.75 and the sprite size is still way smaller than the camera...

i hope you can help me .... thank you ...

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of how the sprite is appearing now?

Comment: Is 2048 the height or width of the image?

Answer (score 1):

[image: PPU Conversion]I got this image from a Brackeys video. You want to divide the number of pixels of the image by the number of units it should take in the game. It sounds like you are on the right track with your math.

Here is an example I just made with the sprite's import settings.
[image: Sprite Import Settings]

And here is the sprite in the scene view.
[image: Scene View]

I am able to successfully make the image cover the entire height of the camera.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, my camera size is 6 this means that the height of the camera is 12 units - my aspect ratio is 4:3 therefore the width of the camera is 16 ..the problem is that the sprite size is  2048x1365 as you can see the aspect ratio of the sprite is different from the game aspect ratio .. and i dont know how to handle this.....

Comment: You will have to provide more information. I am able to get the sprite to behave exactly as you expect. Could you post screenshots of the image import settings and the scene view of the sprite? Thank you.